# Sci fi book or series from the 1980's, constant information

Tags: story-identification

As in the header, I remember very little about this book or series

Some guy who is a key leader, either Earth Government or a corporation or a power bloc. There was a space trading element but I really can't remember anything about that. I don't think this person was the main character.

The key point I remember is, from the moment he wakes up, there's a little device or implant at one of his ears. All day long he gets updated on stock market and political info and military dispersals. A continuous low murmur.

Comment: Gore Burnelli from the Commonwealth saga ? But he is from the 00's and constant information flow comes from direct brain-internet interface, not an specific ear implant.

Comment: No, it was deffo earlier than that I read it, I remember discussing such a thing with a workmate, when I was at the coalmine, and I finished there in the late eighties.

Comment: Darn, my first thought was _[Aristoi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aristoi_(novel))_ (1992) by Walter Jon Williams.

Comment: @Spencer thanks for the suggestion but it wasn't Aristoi. I'd never  heard of Aristoi but I've downloaded it now to read at some time

Comment: Kinda reminds me of the Black Adept's Proton counterpart from *Juxtaposition*; he was (approximately) described as being perpetually plugged into an information umbilicus that kept him constantly apprised of everything going on.

Comment: Ora:cle by Kevin O'Donnell, Jr.? Published in 1984 and my memory is hazy on the actual storyline, but your description immediately reminded me of this book. I think it even begins with a description of the main character waking up and skimming messages and news on his implant. There are aliens and humans trade with them. The protagonist is connected to a worldwide computer network as an expert in his field, so a leader in some sense. The universal presence of information (and, as it later turns out, absence of particular information) plays a big role in the book.

Comment: @Ernst de Ridder that sounds very promising, I think it's maybe the one. I'm trying to get a copy now to have a look

Comment: Well I managed to get a copy of Oracle by Kevin O'Donnell Jr. It was indeed the book I was looking for. @Ernst de Ridder :- do you wanna post it as an answer and I'll accept?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[*ORA:CLE*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1455438.ORA) by Kevin O'Donnell, Jr.? Published in 1983 and my memory is hazy on the actual storyline, but your description immediately reminded me of this book. I think it even begins with a description of the main character waking up and skimming messages and news on his implant. There are aliens and humans trade with them. The protagonist is connected to a worldwide computer network as an expert in his field, so a leader in some sense. The universal presence of information (and, as it later turns out, absence of particular information) plays a big role in the book.